# Undefined offset: 0 if no record in db

Tags: php

Hi i wanna to display image from server. It works when i got a record in DB. But if  there isnt record in DB (no img uploaded) i wanna display NO LOGO

here is my codes:

```
public function display_logo($service_id){
    $img_path = DB::table("logo_table")->get()->where("service_id",$service_id);        
       return $img_path[0];}


public function my_name($id)
{
    $name = $this->get_user()->where('id',$id);
    $image_path = $this->display_logo($id);
    $count = count($image_path);
    return view('my_object', compact("name","image_path","count"));
}
```

And the blade

```
 @if ($count>0)
    <img src="{{$image_path->logo_path}}{{$image_path->logo_name}}" width=100 height=100";>
@else
    <h2>No image</h2>
@endif
```

If there is record in DB then i got the img but  if there isnt. i got :Undefined offset: 0
How can i solve it. (Sorry if my english is bad :))

Answer (score 0):

You should chek for a valid value for $img_path or return null eg:

```
  public function display_logo($service_id){
    $img_path = DB::table("logo_table")->get()->where("service_id",$service_id);        
       return (isset($img_path) ? $img_path[0] : NULL );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check how many images are returned and return `NO LOGO` if there aren't any...

```
return (count($img_path)>0) ? $img_path[0] : "NO LOGO";
```

or just check if the first image is set...

```
return isset($img_path[0]) ? $img_path[0] : "NO LOGO";
```

Not sure what value you need to return, but just change `"NO LOGO"` to the value your after.  May need to use `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

An "undefined offset" exception occurs in PHP when trying to access an array key that does not exist. In this case an empty array is being returned since there are no matching records.

This error can be reproduced with this code:

```php
$img_path = [];
echo $img_path[0]; // undefined offset exception
```

An undefined offset exception can be avoided by using a null-coalescing operator (requires PHP 7.0+) or by checking if the index exists before accessing it.

Solution with null-coalescing operator: (PHP 7.0+)

```php
public function display_logo($service_id){
    $img_path = DB::table("logo_table")->get()->where("service_id",$service_id);  
       // fallback to null if [0] does not exist
       return $img_path[0] ?? null;
}
```

Solution with explicit check:

```php
public function display_logo($service_id){
    $img_path = DB::table("logo_table")->get()->where("service_id",$service_id);  
       // fallback to null if [0] does not exist
       return isset($img_path[0]) ? $img_path[0] : null;
}
```